# Keyboard does not properly show in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

The Keyboard does not align properly in landscape mode (see below). The problem still remains even if I comment out all the controls other than edittext, which leads me to believe the problem is not in layout. Any ideas on how I can correct this?

Works fine in portrait.

Here's my manifest file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and simplified layout file for good measure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is emulator issue. You can test it on a real device and see the result.

Comment: Thanks. It is. Any insights on why it does that and how to mitigate?